# Which reinforcement learning methods can be trained off-policy?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

My understanding is that:

- Value-Based methods such as DQN, C51, Rainbow DQN **can** naturally be trained off-policy using a Replay Buffer, without having to account for any kind of off-policy correction.
- Deterministic Policy Gradient methods, such as DDPG or TD3 **can** be trained off-policy, as they don't integrate over actions.
- Stochastic Policy Gradient methods **can't**, on principle, be trained off-policy, as they need to estimate the gradient using the current policy. However using importance sampling, you can correct that off-policiness, eg the way TRPO or ACER does.

So in the end all the major methods: value function approximations, deterministic policy gradient, and stochastic policy gradient, can be trained using a replay buffer.

Is my understanding correct?